# How do i display data that are in between 2 values in a DDL?

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu

I'd like to learn how to code and store the values that are **in between** (including)

```
Session("StartDate") = DropDownList2.SelectedValue
Session("EndDate") = DropDownList3.SelectedValue
```

And if storing the values of `DDL2` and `DDL3` into a `session` is wrong then please correct me! The property of the column chosen as the datasource in the access file is of `DateTime` format by the way.

Greatly Appreciated!

Comment: Sorry mistake. EndDate is in DropDownList3.SelectedValue

Comment: Just to confirm. You have a datasource that contains a list of values in DateTime format that is being bound to two seperate drop down lists. You want to determine the range of dates including the selected values?

Comment: My datasource is linked to a column called SO_Date which is of DateTime format

Comment: Can i do it in the select statement instead? But my WHERE clause is wrong for Access 2010 yea? WHERE Vendor  Like  '%" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue & "%' AND SO.SO_Date Between '%" & DropDownList2.SelectedValue & "%' And '%" & DropDownList3.SelectedValue & "%'", oCnn)

Comment: `Date` with `Between` clause may not work. You may need the date conversion. What is format of `SO_Date` and what is the value of `DropDownList2.SelectedValue`?

Comment: SO_Date is in DateTime format and the values in my DDL2 and DDL3 is basically just the dates retrieved from the database (e.x 12/18/2013 12:00:00AM)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are ordering the items so that they are Ascending you could do something like this;

I'm not sure what you are using (WinForms, WebForms etc) so I created a demo in in ASP.net

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```html
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not(Page.IsPostBack) then
            BindDDL(DropDownList2)
            BindDDL(DropDownList3)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function GetDates() As IEnumerable(Of DateTime)
        Dim ret = New List(Of DateTime)()

        ret.Add(New DateTime(2015, 1, 1))
        ret.Add(New DateTime(2015, 1, 9))
        ret.Add(New DateTime(2015, 1, 2))
        ret.Add(New DateTime(2015, 1, 3))
        ret.Add(New DateTime(2015, 1, 4))
        ret.Add(New DateTime(2015, 1, 5))
        ret.Add(New DateTime(2015, 1, 6))
        ret.Add(New DateTime(2015, 1, 7))
        ret.Add(New DateTime(2015, 1, 8))

        Return ret

    End Function

    Protected Sub BindDDL(ddl As DropDownList)
        ddl.DataSource = GetDates().OrderBy(Function(x) x)
        ddl.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        GetDateRange(DateTime.Parse(DropDownList2.SelectedValue), DateTime.Parse(DropDownList3.SelectedValue))
    End Sub

    Protected Sub DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        GetDateRange(DateTime.Parse(DropDownList2.SelectedValue), DateTime.Parse(DropDownList3.SelectedValue))
    End Sub

    Public Function GetDateRange(fromDate As DateTime, toDate As DateTime) As List(Of DateTime)
        Dim ret As List(Of DateTime) = GetDates().where(Function(x) x >= fromDate andalso x <= toDate).OrderBy(Function(x) x).ToList()
        
        'do something with your List(of DateTime)
        'such as write it to the screen or store it in a Session variable 
        
        Return ret
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help! Appreciate the time you took to help!